# Get shipping cost in the Cart class

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Maybe you can know why I get a problem when trying to use 
getOrderTotal(true, Cart::ONLY_SHIPPING)

I can get the result with getOrderTotal($use_tax, Cart::ONLY_PRODUCTS)
but when trying to get shipping cost I get trouble with memory "Fatal error: Allowed memory size"
256Mb installed

Prestashop 1.6

Comment: Probably you are calling it recursively

Comment: Yes it look like recursive

Answer (score 0):

you can easily get the shipping cost with this method -> getPackageShippingCost()

[image: getPackageShippingCost]

Comment: When I try to do it - got the same result
I try to call it in classes/Cart